# Spring Repository issue

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I seem to be baffled on how JPA Repositories are suppose to work.
In a nut-shell

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {
    protected final static String FK_NAME = "USER_ID";

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<Detail>();
}

@Entity
public class Detail extends AbstractEntity {
    Long userId;

    String hello;
}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

     User findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);
}
```

And here is the only controller in the app:

```
@RestController
public class Home {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    DetailsRepository loanRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "")
    public HttpEntity home() {
        User user = userRepository.findByFirstName("John");

        if (user == null) {
            user = new User();
            user.setFirstName("John");
        }

        Detail detail = new Detail();
        detail.setHello("Hello Msh");

        user.getDetails().add(detail);

        userRepository.save(user);

        return new ResponseEntity("hi", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Below a screenshot from debugging session where the app just started and the get request to home() method creates new user, new detail, adds detail to user.**
[image: New user is created]

**Below example - when the user is saved, the detail entity gets updated**
[image: New user is saved]

**Now on the next request, the old user John is found and has been added a new instance of detail.**
[image: Old user was found]

**The old user has been saved but now the newly created detail does not get updated outside.**
[image: Old user was updated and saves]

How come this only works first time ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What do you expect this code to do, and what does it do instead. Note that you should NOT have a `userId` field in Detail, as this column is handled by the OneToMany association.

Comment: @JBNizet I am asking - why when I create a new User, then add a new Detail to User.details, and SAVE newly created user - the Detail gets updated with an ID, but when I get the created user back from the database, create a new Detail, and add that detail to the user and save user again - the Detail instance in the User.detail list gets updated  but the instance that was passed to the User does not. Why it only works first time.

Comment: Have you committed the transaction and seen if the Details was saved with an ID in the database?

Comment: I am using in memory hsqldb. At least when I fetch them through repositories they are there.

Comment: So, everything works fine. You're simply expecting Hibernate to do things immediately, whereas it does them at flush time.

Comment: @JBNizet well its just inconvenient - also you mentioned I should not have `userId` in my `Detail` entity but when I specify @Query() where reference the @JoinColumn, spring fails to check run that query - if I leave the column however, repository @Query i reference that column with work.

Comment: Spring doesn't run the query. Your JPA implementation does. And if it doesn't run it, that's because it's incorrect, so fix it. You simply need to learn the tools you're using. They won't work the way you think they should work.

Answer (score 1):

Basically theres so much fail going on so that I would advise you to go a step backwards. If youre wana go the short path of getting a solution for exactly this problem continue reading ;)

First part related to the answer of Jaiwo99:
As I can see in the gradle view of intellij, your using Spring Boot. So it is necessary to place @EnableTransactionManagement on top of your configuration class. Otherwise the @Transacion annotation does not have any effect.

Second part your JPA/Hibernate model mapping. Theres so much bad practise on the net that it is no wonder that most beginners have troubles starting with it.

A correct version could look like (not tested)

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="user")
    private List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<Detail>();

    public void addDetail(Detail detail) {
        details.add(detail);
        detail.setUser(user);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Detail extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    private String hello;

    public void setUser(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Some general advice related to creating a model mapping:

- avoid bi-directional mappings whenever possible
- cascade is a decision made on the service level and not at the model level and can have huge drawbacks. So for beginners avoid it.
- I have no idea why people like to put JoinColumn, JoinTable and whatever join annotation on top of fields. The only reason to do this is when you have a legacy db (my opinion). When you do not like the names created by your jpa provider, provide a different naming strategy.
- I would provide a custom name for the user class, because this is in some databases a reserved word.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing - lets suppose that `Detail` entity does not have a back reference to `User` entity. A uni-directional mapping an example found [here ](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29) the join column creates an additional column so that you can still query the `EMPLEOYEE` when you have `PHONE`. How would one do that with spring data '@Query', as far as I have tried everythign just fails cause there is no physical property on the @Entity

Comment: I would remove the reference to Detail from the User. In that case you avoid the n +1 select problem too. Beside that it is possible to query it with something like the following "Select u From User u Where :detail MEMBER Of u.details".
Please mark the message as correct when your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, the first time you saved a new entity outside of hibernate session,  the second time, the user object you got is a detached object, by default hibernate will not consider it is changed in this case.

*solution *
Move this logic to another service class, which annotated with @transactional 
Or 
Annotate your controller with transactional 
Or 
Override equals and hashCode method on user class may also help

Comment: I have tried annotating with javax.transaction.Transactional or org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional, I still get the same result... it is actually very strange.